# Sed N command appears to delete line if empty

Tags: sed

This code removes newlines, then quotes and separates the characters.

Semicolon isn't working. Piping to a second sed does work, but the semicolon doesn't.

Script

```
# Piping works
echo "$1" | sed -r ':a;N;s/\n/\\n/;$!ba' | sed -r 's/(\\?.)/'"'\1',/g"
# Semicolon doesn't work on single lines
echo "$1" | sed -r ':a;N;s/\n/\\n/;$!ba;s/(\\?.)/'"'\1',/g"
# Skipping N command on single line works
echo "$1" | sed -r ':a;$bb;N;s/\n/\\n/;$!ba;:b;s/(\\?.)/'"'\1',/g"
```

Output:

```
$ wchar "test\n"
't','e','s','t','\n',
test\n
't','e','s','t','\n',
$ wchar "test
test"
't','e','s','t','\n','t','e','s','t',
't','e','s','t','\n','t','e','s','t',
't','e','s','t','\n','t','e','s','t',
```

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: The input is in the second code block, the first response is the expected output, the second is what I get when I don't use a pipe

Comment: please mention that// . It's consufing me and also remove the `$` symbol.

Comment: Last I checked `$` (or `#`) were fairly standard shell prompts

Comment: I don't know what is `wchar` .. Is this a command?

Comment: Please clarify - what is the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you run into is that the first line is also the last one (note that `"test\n"` does not contain a newline but a backslash), so the first `N` command is executed before any test whether the current line is the last one and ends up trying to fetch past the end.

Since all you're trying to do with the label and `N` loop is to assemble the file into the hold buffer (the replacement of the newlines can wait until afterwards), I suggest the following replacement:

```
echo -e "test\n" | sed -rn '1h;1!H;${x;s/\n/\\n/g; s/(\\?.)/'\''\1'\'', /g;p}'
```

This follows the basic pattern

```
sed -n '1 h; 1! H; $ { x; do stuff; p }'
```

...in other words, it reads the file into the hold buffer, swaps it back into the pattern space when the last line is being handled (i.e., when the whole file is in the hold buffer), does stuff with it and then prints the result. The `s` commands in place of `do stuff` are lifted from your code.

Comment: Hmm, what about the `-z` option? If I use that it will load the whole thing in at the start, or is there a reason not to use that?

Comment: As long as your text or file contains no null bytes and you use GNU sed, sure, that'll work.

Comment: It's actually coming from stdin - AFAIK no shells allow `nul`s so yay!